# Making content type read only for log entries in the Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

In my `admin.py` I have

```
class LogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = (
        'user', 'content_type_id', 'object_id', 'object_repr',
        'action_flag', 'change_message'
    )

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

and

```
admin.site.register(LogEntry, LogEntryAdmin)
```

While I figured out adding `'user'` rather than `'user_id'`, I can't figure out what to add instead of `'content_type_id'` to make the content type read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs for LogEntry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/admin/models/), the field is just named `content_type`.
Using that should get you a read-only content type field in the admin.